# jQuery.get() only works with certain webpages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, get

On my webpage [here](https://steepatticstairs.github.io/weather/combined.html), I combine a bunch of weather APIs into one page. I have recently been experimenting with the weather.gov API, and it has worked to great success.

However, there are some bits of data that I want to query, that weather.gov will not provide through a simple API request. For example, if you input a zip code on my webpage linked above, and get the weather data for a location, you can scroll down to the bottom and see a chart with various weather items. This is provided by weather.gov, but is not provided through a JSON API request. I had to load the webpage with the graph with `$.get()`, and then parse the resulting HTML output to extract all of the `<img>` tags, and then get the right one. This is the code I used for that:

```js
// gets the plotter image URL (10th in the array of images on the plotter page)
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772776/
$.get(`https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?marine=0&zmx=1&zmy=1&FcstType=graphical&lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&Submit=Submit`, function(data, status){
   var pictures = [],
   m;
   var str = data,
   rex =  /<img[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*/gi;
                
   while (m = rex.exec( str )) {
      pictures.push( m[1] );
   }

   const allImages = [];
   var index = 0;
   pictures.forEach(function(picture){
      allImages.push(picture);
   })
   var correctImage = "https://forecast.weather.gov/" + allImages[10];
   console.log(correctImage);
   document.getElementById('graph').setAttribute('src', correctImage);
});
```

This code will take all of the images off of that webpage that generates the graph, store them in an array, and then retrieve the 10th item of the array - the item where my desired image is.

However, if I replace the URL in the `$.get()` method above with a different URL, in this case `https://www.weather.gov/lwx/`, it gives me the console error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.weather.gov/lwx/ due to access control checks.
```

I don't think it's an issue of `http` vs `https`, as both URLs are `https` but only one works.

If anybody has any idea what the issue might be, I would appreciate your help. It might have something to do with headers, but I am not sure and wouldn't know how to implement them anyways.

Answer (score -1):

The site you are trying to load is on different domain, so you must follow the Access Control rules

You can only load certain types of resources without it

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Duplicate of:
[Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: I understand that's the issue, I'm asking how you would fix it.

Comment: @SteepAtticStairs You need to be the owner of the domain and add in the request the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to allow different domains to use that page. 

If you are using it oly ofr yourself than jsut start the browser with --disable-web-security

Please read the links i sent you